# How to get and sort a few columns based on their values?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I am trying to create a table from another table.
The catch is to compare 3 different columns where a different columns is null.

- Will "Compare ItemID1, ItemID2 and ItemID3, take only those that have value in it and make it to one row"
- No will always be the biggest. If the column consist of Yes and No, No will be selected
- Take note. One CustomerID can have multiple different ItemID

Example 1

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 |   Value    |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
|          1 | abc     | xyz     | cde     | Yes        |
|          1 | abc     | null    | cde     | No         |
|          1 | null    | xyz     | cde     | No         |
|          1 | abc     | xyz     | cde     | No         |
|          1 | iop     | tyu     | ghj     | Yes        |
|          1 | iop     | null    | ghj     | Yes        |
|          1 | iop     | tyu     | ghj     | Yes        |
|          1 | null    | tyu     | ghj     | Yes        |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Expected result would be

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 | Value |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
|          1 | abc     | xyz     | cde     | No    |
|          1 | iop     | tyu     | ghj     | Yes   |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Example 2

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 |   Value    |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
|          1 | qwe     | null    | asd     | No         |
|          1 | qwe     | null    | asd     | Yes        |
|          1 | null    | null    | asd     | Yes        |
|          1 | qwe     | null    | asd     | Yes        |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Expected result would be

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 | Value |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
|          1 | qwe     | null    | asd     | No    |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Example 3

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 |   Value    |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
|          1 | fgh     | null    | zxc     | Yes        |
|          1 | fgh     | xyv     | zxc     | Yes        |
|          1 | null    | null    | zxc     | Yes        |
|          1 | fgh     | null    | zxc     | Yes        |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Expected result would be

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 | Value |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
|          1 | fgh     | xyv     | zxc     | Yes   |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

### What I have tried.

I have tried in, Codes are below. but receiving the wrong results.
It seems like it is only taking the first, base on ItemID1

Tried Example

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 |   Value    |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
|          1 | fgh     | null    | zxc     | Yes        |
|          1 | fgh     | xyv     | zxc     | No         |
|          1 | null    | null    | zxc     | Yes        |
|          1 | fgh     | null    | zxc     | Yes        |
|          1 | iop     | tyu     | ghj     | Yes        |
|          1 | iop     | null    | ghj     | Yes        |
|          1 | iop     | tyu     | ghj     | Yes        |
|          1 | null    | tyu     | ghj     | Yes        |
|          2 | abc     | xyz     | cde     | Yes        |
|          2 | abc     | null    | cde     | No         |
|          2 | null    | xyz     | cde     | No         |
|          2 | abc     | xyz     | cde     | No         |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Result Return

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 | Value |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
|          1 | fgh     | null    | zxc     | Yes   |
|          1 | iop     | tyu     | ghj     | Yes   |
|          2 | abc     | xyz     | cde     | Yes   |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Expected result would be

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| CustomerID | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 | Value |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
|          1 | fgh     | xyz     | zxc     | No    |
|          1 | iop     | tyu     | ghj     | Yes   |
|          2 | abc     | xyz     | cde     | No    |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Code that I tried.

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
    (CustomerID,
     ItemID1,
     ItemID2,
     ItemID3,
     Value)
SELECT
     CustomerID,
     ItemID1,
     ItemID2,
     ItemID3,
     Value
FROM (SELECT
     CustomerID,
     ItemID1,
     ItemID2,
     ItemID3,
     Value,
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID1 ORDER BY ETA DESC)rn
     FROM ETA_TABLE)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your expected output.  What are the rules for filling in `NULL` values for customers whose items have more than one non `NULL` value?

Comment: @IvanSim . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MAX(ItemID1) AS ItemID1,
    MAX(ItemID2) AS ItemID2,
    MAX(ItemID3) AS ItemID3,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 'No' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Value
FROM ETA_TABLE
GROUP BY
    CustomerID;
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Thanks for answering, I don't understand how does this row works.

    CASE WHEN COUNT(VALUE) <> COUNT(*) THEN MAX(VALUE) END AS Value.

Is Null value the max?

Comment: Before I address anything, can you explain why you expect a `NULL` output in the `Value` column for all cases?

Comment: Ohh sorry I actually made a mistake. It doesnt need to be null. The Value column is suppose to be a yes or no. No is the bigger then Yes, so if a record consist of yes and no, the end result should display No only. If the record consist of only yes then the end result should display  Yes only

Comment: No idea what you're talking about now.  None of your sample data has yes or no in it.

Comment: Hi @Tim I have edited the questions. For better understanding i change the data too. Now the Value is Yes or no. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: I edited my answer, I think the only tricky logic for you is in handling the `Value` column.

Comment: Hey @Tim, Sorry again, after taking sometime to digest the code and test it. I have notice that I forget to mention that each CustomerID can have multiple types of ItemID. I have update the question and result for better understanding. Sorry again, my carelessness got me

Comment: And it seems like If cannot be use in sum in Mssql, so I change it to Case statement

Comment: Then why did you tag with MySQL?  I edited my answer.

Comment: Ops Sorry my bad.

Comment: but so far i dont think we can use group by CustomerID because CustomerID can have multiple ItemID.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*,
       (select min(value)
        from t t2
        where t2.CustomerID = t.CustomerID and
              (t2.ItemID1 = t.ItemID1 or
               t2.ItemID2 = t.ItemID2 or
               t2.ItemID3 = t.ItemID3
              )
       ) as valu
from (select distinct CustomerID, ItemID1, ItemID2, ItemID3
      from t
      where ItemID1 is not null and
            ItemID2 is not null and
            ItemID3 is not null
     ) t;
```

`MIN()` has the nice property that it will return `'No'` if any of the values are `'No'`.

Note:  Your sample data has disjoint sets for the items -- there are no overlaps.  If that is present in your actual data, and this does not solve your problem, you should ask another question.